# C++ type checking when using templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I have a Linked list class defined as such,

```
template <typename Bin> 
    class LinkedList {
    ...
    struct node{
        Bin value;
        ...
    };
...
};
```

and in there I want to override the == operator to check if two lists are equal. I've got it set up and working for cases where the the types are the same. e.g.

```
LinkedList<int> a;
LinkedList<int> b;
a == b;
```

works just fine but I get a compiler error if there's a comparison between different types. Is there any workaround this aside from just assuming no mismatched types will be compared?

Comment: So you're saying you want to be able to compare lists that have different types?

Comment: @Brian: For example comparing a `LinkedList<int>` to a `LinkedList<long>` seems meaningful to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
  struct List
  {

  };

template<class L, class R> 
  auto operator==(const List<L>& l, const List<R>& r)
  -> decltype(std::declval<L>() == std::declval<R>())
{
  bool same = true;
  // run through l and r comparing elements
  // this function will only expand if there is a valid comparison
  // between an L and an R

  return same;
}


int main()
{
  List<int> x;
  List<double> y;

  auto same = x == y;
}
```